# SQL 2005 - Query to Find Tables with Most Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I searched for this for a while but came up empty ... hopefully someone here can help.

Is there a query I can run on a database (SQL Server 2005) that will return the number of rows in each table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080701045806/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-and-their-row-counts.html):

```
SELECT 
    [TableName] = so.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects so, 
    sysindexes si 
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U' 
    AND 
    si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
GROUP BY 
    so.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
```

Comment: don't use the sysobjects and sysindexes system tables anymore - please! They'll soon be deprecated, and SQL Server 2005 introduced the new "sys" schema that has all the necessary views - sys.tables, sys.indexes and more - use those instead!

Comment: just so you know, this will not return the exact row counts

Answer (score 4):

Galwegian got it almost right :-) For SQL Server 2005 and up, I always recommed using the "sys.*" system views instead of the (soon to be deprecated) sysobjects and sysindexes tables.

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS 'Table Name',
    SUM(p.[Rows]) as 'Row Count'
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
    i.index_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    t.NAME 
ORDER BY 
    SUM(p.[Rows]) DESC
```

Marc

Answer (score 1):

here's my version which uses a dm_db_partition_stats DMV:

```
SELECT object_name(object_id) as table_name,
    SUM (row_count) AS total_number_of_rows 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE   (index_id=0 or index_id=1)
group by object_name(object_id)
order by SUM (row_count) desc
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked so far with tables not in the dbo schema

Answer (score 0):

this will return row_count, col_count, data_size

enjoy!.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/10/sql-server-query-to-find-number-rows-columns-bytesize-for-each-table-in-the-current-database-find-biggest-table-in-database/

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I got this, I'm pretty sure I didn't write it and it's definitely overkill but it's still fun.

```
USE master
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @EnumDBs TABLE ([id] INT IDENTITY, [sql] VARCHAR(1024), PRIMARY KEY ([id]))
CREATE TABLE #EnumTables ([id] INT IDENTITY, [db] SYSNAME, [owner] SYSNAME, [table] SYSNAME, PRIMARY KEY ([db], [owner], [table], [id]))
CREATE TABLE #TableMetrics ([id] INT IDENTITY, [db] SYSNAME NULL, [table] SYSNAME, [rows] INT, [reserved] VARCHAR(256), [data] VARCHAR(256), [index_size] VARCHAR(256), [unused] VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY ([table], [id]))

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @db SYSNAME

INSERT INTO @EnumDBs
SELECT '    USE ['+name+']
        DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
        INSERT INTO #EnumTables
        SELECT  '''+name+''' AS [db]
                , u.name AS [owner]
                , o.name AS [table]
        FROM sysobjects AS o
        JOIN sysusers AS u
        ON o.uid = u.uid
        WHERE type = ''U''
        ORDER BY    u.name
                , o.name' AS [sql]
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE dbid > 4

SELECT @i=COUNT(*)
    , @sql=''
FROM @EnumDBs
WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @sql = SQL
    FROM @EnumDBs
    WHERE ID = @i

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        EXEC(@sql)

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0) GOTO ERR_HANDLER

    SET @i=@i-1
END

SELECT @i=COUNT(*)
    , @sql=''
FROM #EnumTables

WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @db=[db]
        , @sql='USE ['+[db]+'] EXEC SP_SPACEUSED ''['+[db]+'].['+[owner]+'].['+[table]+']'''
    FROM #EnumTables
    WHERE ID = @i

    --PRINT @SQL
    INSERT INTO #TableMetrics
    ([table], [rows], [reserved], [data], [index_size], [unused])
    EXEC(@sql)
    IF (@@ERROR <> 0) GOTO ERR_HANDLER

    UPDATE #TableMetrics
        SET [db]=@db
    WHERE [db] IS NULL
    IF (@@ERROR <> 0) GOTO ERR_HANDLER

    SET @i=@i-1
END

SELECT * FROM #TableMetrics ORDER BY [db], CAST(REPLACE([reserved],' KB','') AS INT) DESC

ERR_HANDLER:
DROP TABLE #EnumTables
DROP TABLE #TableMetrics
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create table:

```
create table maxRows (tablename varchar(900) primary key,CountOf int)
```

run this and copy the output:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'print ''INSERT INTO maxRows SELECT ''''?'''', COUNT(*) FROM ? WITH (NOLOCK)'''
```

run the copied output, it inserts into the table a row count for each table

now run this, lists the tables with their row count:

```
select countOf,tablename from maxRows order by CountOf DESC
```

Comment: wow, could cause a lot of table blocking if you run it as read committed

Comment: @marc_s, thsi returns the actual table counts, not estimates

Comment: duh, follow this link: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-and-their-row-counts.html there is a solution just like mine using _sp_msforeachtable_, written better (but without the NOLOCK)...

Comment: @KM: OK, true - you get the actual, current row count - but it seems a bit overkill (at least to me), unless you really absolutely have to have the exact numbers.

Comment: @marc_s, FYI, in the link im my comment above, there is an example of a stored procedure that uses the same technique, but captures the result set from sp_msforeachtable into the temp table without the need to copy/paste the output like I do...  cleaner if you like that way.  this is fine if you want one off run.  btw when I ran my solution on a dev system, my top count table (some odd history log table) was not even listed by your solution at least in the top ten.  so the estimate can be way off...

Answer (score 0):

When run in a database, the following returns table row counts and index/total space usage.

```
declare @tableName  varchar(100);

create table
    #table
    (
        tablename   sysname,
        row_count   int,
        reserved    varchar(50),
        data        varchar(50),
        index_size  varchar(50),
        unused      varchar(50)
    );

create table
    #table2
    (
        tableName   varchar(100),
        row_count   int,
        data_size   int,
        index_size  int,
        reserved    int,
        unused      int
    );

declare C_T cursor fast_forward for
    select      TableName = '[' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + ']'
    from        sys.tables t
                inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where       t.type = 'U'
    order by    s.name,
                t.name;

open    C_T;

fetch next from C_T into @tableName;

while   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        truncate table  #table;

        insert into #table
        exec        sp_spaceused @tableName, false;

        insert into #table2(tableName, row_count, data_size, index_size, reserved, unused)
        select      @tableName,
                    row_count,
                    convert(int, replace(data, ' KB', '')),
                    convert(int, replace(index_size, ' KB', '')),
                    convert(int, replace(reserved, ' KB', '')),
                    convert(int, replace(unused, ' KB', ''))
        from        #table;

        fetch next from C_T into @tableName;
    end

close       C_T;
deallocate  C_T;

select      [Table Name] = tableName,
            [Rows] = row_count,
            [Data Size (KB)] = data_size,
            [Indexes Size (KB)] = index_size,
            [Reserved Space (KB)] = reserved,
            [Unused Space (KB)] = unused
from        #table2
order by    data_size desc;

drop table      #table;
drop table      #table2;
```